# Click event not executed if my blur event remove the element

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a dynamic dropdown list that items inside can be clicked(will do something)

- When focus, it will show some suggestion items
- When blur, it will remove the items inside the list node

The problem is when the blur/focusout event trigger, my element removed, and the click event do not trigger.

Here is the minimal reproduce in codepen: https://codepen.io/XiaoChu/pen/NWYJdvj?editors=1111

HTML:

```html
<div class="search-wrapper">
  <input id="keyword-search" type="text" placeholder="Type some keywords...">
  <ul id="result-list"></ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
const inputDom = document.getElementById('keyword-search');
const listDom = document.getElementById('result-list');

inputDom.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = `item-${i + 1}`;
    li.classList.add('item');
    li.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      alert(e.currentTarget.innerText);
    });
    listDom.appendChild(li);
  }
});

inputDom.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  listDom.innerHTML = '';
});
```

I have tried `setTimeout` to wait some milliseconds, and it works. But I want to know is this solution a good way?

Comment: You can see the problem, right?  As soon as you click the item, the input box has to lose focus before the click event can be dispatched.  There may be a complicated way to handle it with flags, but if the timeout works, that's what you should do.

Comment: If this something simple that will not evolve to be more complex, then fine, set a timeout. But something like this is generally kept track of outside of simply focus state. You'd keep track of and manage the focus/open state. In your case, maybe you open it on the focus event, and close it on one or more other click events.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, I do know the problem.  Just want to sure that my solution isn't a bad way, lol. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @AlienWithPizza I think in my case is simple, there's no multiple selections in an action. Thanks for your adivce!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `flag`, `mouseover` and `mouseleave` like this

```js
const inputDom = document.getElementById('keyword-search');
const listDom = document.getElementById('result-list');

let isInList;
listDom.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  isInList = true;
  console.log(isInList);
})
listDom.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isInList = false;
  console.log(isInList)
})

inputDom.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = `item-${i + 1}`;
    li.classList.add('item');
    li.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      alert(e.currentTarget.innerText);
    });
    listDom.appendChild(li);
  }
});

inputDom.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  if(!isInList){
     listDom.innerHTML = '';
  }
});
```

Comment: You give me another point to solve this problem, thanks!